# Disable Drag and Drop tinyMCE without opening the images

Tags: drag-and-drop, tinymce

> hello everyone,
>
> i hope that everything is going well for all of you.
>
> i have question, i'm using TinyMCE 3.4.6 in my project, and i want to
> disable drag and drop images, so i add the parameter
> `paste_block_drop` to `true`, but when i try to drag and drop the
> image the Browser open it in the same page.  i want to block the drag
> and drop without opening the image when someone try to drar and drop
> image.
>
> Can someone have a clue ? thanks for all of you

Answer (score 0):

You may want to upgrade to a newer version of TinyMCE. This may have been fixed since the version you're using was released.

Comment: thanks @idempotency, but i have another issue, when i use browser Mozilla the image can be add but when i use browser Chrome the image is open in other url